# Shifting bits in MIPS

Tags: byte, mips, bit, shift

My professor gave an example to us:

```
Say your integer is 57412476 which is 0x36C0B7C. If you take out bits 
19,20, and 21 and store them in $a0 as the least significant three 
bits, you will get 5 in decimal in $a0.
```

Can someone explain to me how this works? For clarification, if register $a0 contain bits 19,20, and 21 of user input (call it A), the least significant bit of $a0 should contain the 19th bit of A, the second least significant bit of $a0 should contain the 20th bit of A, and so on...

Comment: Bit numbering starts at 0, so bit 19 is the 20th bit. Anyway, it's a trivial problem: open `calc.exe` in Windows (or some comparable program on whatever OS you use), enter `57412476`, tell the calculator to show the number in binary form, pick out the 3 relevant bits and enter those into the calculator while in binary mode, then switch back to decimal mode.

Comment: @Michael So I put 57412476 into a calculator to convert to binary and I get, 11011011000000101101111100. Then I picked out the three relevant bits for bits 19, 20, and 21, which are 1,1,1 respectively. This is 7 in decimal and not 5. I'm still confused how the answer is 5.

EDIT: realized I started I was starting at the wrong end LOL. I finally got 5 as the answer. Thank you!